# Understanding offset-k method of representing negative integers

Tags: binary

I'm reading [this article](https://vineetgupta22.wordpress.com/tag/offset-binary-representation/) about offset-k method of representing negative integers. Can someone please explain the following passage using some examples:

> One logical way to represent signed integers is to have enough range
> in binary numbers so that the zero can be offset to the middle of the
> range of positive binary numbers. Then the magnitude of a negative
> binary number can be simply subtracted from that zero point.

I understand the mechanics, e.g. to represent number 4 in 11 bits, I'll do `4+1023=1027`, but can't understand the logic behind it and why it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we have numbers ranging from -8 to +8 we can remove the sign by adding 8 to all of or numbers. The numbers would then be 0 to +16. It is rather like shifting the scale (as in converting *Celsius* to *Kelvin*) to obtain only positive values.

This representation allows operations on the biased numbers to be the same as for unsigned integers, but actually represents both positive and negative values.

This method is called by several names - **Excess-K**, also called **offset binary** or **biased representation**, uses a fixed value K as a biasing value.

A value is represented by the unsigned number which is K greater than the intended value.

***Biased representations*** are now primarily used for the exponent of floating-point numbers. The IEEE floating-point standard defines the exponent field of a single-precision (32-bit) number as an 8-bit excess-127 field.

To understand More clearly the two examples below:

## Example:1

4-bit Pattern

0110 the digit/column value of the most significant bit is 8, so 4 bit patterns are referred to as an Excess (8) notation.

- To convert this example find the sum value of the entire pattern as though a standard binary number:

  ```
  =(0 x 8) + (1 x 4) + (1 x 2) + (0 x 1 ) 
  =0      +   4      +   2     +   0
  =6
  ```
- Then subtract the excess value,8, from the sum,  (6 - 8)
- The result is a signed value, -2.

## Example 2

5-bit pattern

11110, the digit/column value of the most significant bit is 16, so 5-bit patterns are referred to as an Excess (16) notation.

- To convert this example find the sum value of the entire pattern as though a standard binary number:

  ```
  (1x16) + (1x8) + (1x4) + (1x2) + (0x1)
  = 16   +    8  +   4   +   2   +   0
  = 30
  ```
- Then subtract the current excess value, 16, from the sum,  (30 - 16)
- The result is a signed value, + 14.

Hope it will clear the logic behind and  understand that sign bit of 0 represents the negative sign and 1 represents the non-negative sign to denote a signed value

Comment: thanks, can please elaborate a bit on your last paragraph?